# How to fix 'Call was rejected by callee' error while converting Word to PDF using Python

Tags: python, pdf, ms-word, file-conversion, office-automation

Im trying to convert word files to PDFs using python but I cant get this code to work.

```
import os
import comtypes.client

word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(input_file)
doc.SaveAs(output_file, FileFormat=17)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()

input_file = "C:\\input.docx"
output_file = "C:\\output.pdf"
doc_to_pdf(input_file, output_file)
```

Trying to run this but getting an error "comtypes.COMError: (-2147418111, 'Call was rejected by callee.', None, None)"

Comment: Where and when do you run the code? is it run from a server or service app?

Comment: from my host, im trying to mass convert doc's to pdf.

Comment: Where and when do you run the code? is it run by the user?